# Get a record with maxid and condition in mysql in yii, but sometime it get second record?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

**my table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `the_kho_chi_tiet_with_id` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ngay_thang` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `ma_phieu` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_san_pham` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_kho` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `khoi_luong_nhap` double NOT NULL,
  `so_luong_nhap` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `khoi_luong_xuat` double NOT NULL,
  `so_luong_xuat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `khoi_luong_ton` double NOT NULL,
  `so_luong_ton` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kho_du_tru` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

**PHP code:**

```
$sql = "SELECT so_luong_ton, khoi_luong_ton, kho_du_tru FROM the_kho_chi_tiet_with_id WHERE id_kho = $id_kho and id_san_pham = $id_san_pham ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1";
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$dataReader=$command->queryAll();
if($dataReader!=null)
{
    foreach($dataReader as $row)
    {
       .................
    }
}

**Get a record with maxid and condition in mysql in yii, *but sometime it get second record* !?**
```

Comment: What do you mean by `second record`? Second record by ID or two records are returned?

Comment: Example: Maxid in table is 53, but sometime it get id = 52.

Comment: And does `$id_kho` and `$id_san_pham` fits only to `#53`?

Comment: but why don't you actually use a yii model for this stuff? this may not help with this issue, but in geenral it is better to use the modesl, so you also can avoid errors in your syntax

Comment: Anybody have any method to do this, can tell me !

Comment: maybe you could also add the values of  `$id_san_pham` and `$id_kho`

Comment: And does $id_kho and $id_san_pham fits only to #53? –  Justinas  ==> they are good parameter, no problem.

Comment: if you think the params are oK, then i would suggest you try to debug, see what Sql request is actually done, and try it manually on your DB, maybe there you find the error

Comment: $sql = "SELECT so_luong_ton, khoi_luong_ton, kho_du_tru FROM the_kho_chi_tiet_with_id WHERE id_kho = ".$id_kho." and id_san_pham = ".$id_san_pham." ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1"; ==> This sql how difference a below sql ?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Please check with the below, hope it works!..if not please tell...

  $id_kho=373;//sample value declaration
  $id_san_pham=1;//sample value declaration

  $select="select max(id) as id,so_luong_ton, khoi_luong_ton, kho_du_tru from  
               the_kho_chi_tiet_with_id where users_ref_id=".$id_kho." and   
          status=".$id_san_pham;
  $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($select)->queryRow(); 
  $Maxid=$command['id'];
  $so_luong_ton=$command['so_luong_ton'];
  $khoi_luong_ton=$command['khoi_luong_ton'];
  $kho_du_tru=$command['kho_du_tru'];
```

Comment: Wrong to use "select max(id)", I think only query that:==>$sql = "SELECT so_luong_ton, khoi_luong_ton,kho_du_tru FROM the_kho_chi_tiet_with_id WHERE id_kho = ".$id_kho." and id_san_pham = ".$id_san_pham." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

Comment: You can try with this also,
  You can also use bind parameter and put the where clause in your createCommand.


$query = Yii::app()->db
  ->createCommand("SELECT tableColumn FROM tableName ORDER BY tableColumn DESC LIMIT 1")
  ->where('cond1=:cond1', array(':cond1'=>$cond1))
  ->queryRow();

http://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

  Above  Link is for just to understand the performance.

Comment: @chomiendong.com.. Can't understand ,could you please detail me in simple way.

Comment: I think, the problem is conflict. It mean that when I get record have max_id, and then before i insert new record, having another process insert new record was inserted. if such cases happen, so how to handle to fix above problem?

Comment: @chomiendong.com  Could you tell me how the conflict happened & show some coding ,if so sure will give the solution based on understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the problem is conflict. It mean that when I get record have max_id, and then before i insert new record, having another process insert new record was inserted.
if such cases happen, so how to handle to fix above problem?

Answer (score 0):

**My solution:**

```
$lock = $connection->createCommand('LOCK TABLES `the_kho_chi_tiet_with_id` READ');
$lock->execute();
$sql = "SELECT so_luong_ton, khoi_luong_ton, kho_du_tru FROM the_kho_chi_tiet_with_id WHERE id_kho = $id_kho and id_san_pham = $id_san_pham ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1";
$command=$connection->createCommand($sql);
$dataReader=$command->queryAll();
if($dataReader!=null)
{
    foreach($dataReader as $row)
    {
       .................
    }
}
//Insert new record here
TheKhoChiTietWithId::model()->InsertNewRecord(1,300,1,333,1);

$unlock = $connection->createCommand('UNLOCK TABLES');
$unlock->execute();
```

I lock table to keep no other session work to this table.